# Gráficar listas en secuencia

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente programa que me superpone las tres listas en un solo plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
veces=[1,2,3]
lista_a=[-4,-1,0,2,4,9] 
lista_b=[-39,-38,-42,-46,-45,-35]
lista_c=[-23,-28,-27,-29,-30,-27]   
plt.figure()
for item in range(len(veces)):
    plt.plot(item)
plt.show()
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que cada plot me salga uno al costado del otro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para plotear en la misma figura uno al costado del otro, tenes que usar `subplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

lista_a=[-4,-1,0,2,4,9] 
lista_b=[-39,-38,-42,-46,-45,-35]
lista_c=[-23,-28,-27,-29,-30,-27] 
listas = [lista_a,lista_b,lista_c] 
 
plt.figure(figsize = (12,6))

for idx,lista in enumerate(listas,1):
    plt.subplot(1,len(listas),idx)
    plt.plot(lista)
plt.show()
```

Paso a explicar cada parte:

1. creo una lista con cada lista a plotear para ir recorriendola y hacer cada gráfico.
2. creo la figura ( la hago más ancha para que se vea mejor el plot)
3. recorro las `listas` con un enumerate, esto permite tener cada lista individual y un índice.
   La función `subplot` de `plt` permite crear subfiguras y la sintaxis clásica es `plt.subplot(nFilas,nCols,val)` donde nFilas y nCols son la cantidad de filas y columnas que quiero que tenga el gráfico (en este caso 1 fila y 3 columnas) y `val`
   es la coordenada donde hacer el gráfico (1, 2 o 3),

---

**Edit**

Para poner todo en los mismos ejes concatenando las listas:

```
concatenadas =[elem for lista in listas for elem in lista]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(concatenadas)
```

la primer línea concatena todos los elementos de las sublistas en una lista única y luego se grafica.

Comment: Muchas gracias, como podría hacer para que ambas curvas estén una al costado de otra y en el mismo eje x

Comment: no entiendo, te referís como a continuación? podrías hacer `concatenadas =[elem for lista in listas for elem in lista]` y luego graficar con `plt.plot(concatenadas)`
básicamente es crear una nueva lista que tenga los elementos de todas las listas